# What's a good RCA capture card for streaming media?

Tags: linux, video, video-capture

We are putting together an e-sports team at college and among the games we play. There's Project M on the Wii and Melee on the GameCube, so we need a CVBS/RCA video capture card to record and upload our gameplay.

So far we have tried with an Encore and a GreenLeaf video capture card without any success. We were unable to find any decent USB/PCI/PCIe capture cards that support this kind of input. What is a good hardware choice for this? It must be compatible with Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had good success with the following card on Mac:

[Diamond VC500](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBlBR9s82JU)

It has Linux support as well according to the link, but I have not tested it. Here are the specifications:

- USB 2.0
- Supports NTSC and PAL
- Captures Composite RCA or S-Video input
- 640 x 480 @30FPS NTSC video capture
- 720 x 576 @25FPS PAL video capture
- Included Software: Videoglide for Mac OS, EZGrabber for Windows

**References**

- [VC500 MAC FAQs](https://www.diamondmm.com/vc500mac-faqs.html)
- [VC500 Quick Installation Guide](https://www.diamondmm.com/vc500-quick-installation-guide.html)
- [EZGrabber Video Capture Driver](http://www.driverguide.com/driver/detail.php?driverid=1803090)
- [VideoGlide for Mac OSX](http://www.echofx.com/videoglide.html)